# How to override CSS code with a new class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to override a CSS style that puts a border from some previous code. What am I doing wrong?

```css
/* previous code */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li {
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  }
}

/* code to override and remove border */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .navbar-nav>li .noborder {
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left noborder">  //this should override the previous code
    <li>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="picture.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right!  It still does the same issue though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `li` and `.noborder` definition.

```
/*                                    v-----------< The space here */
@media (min-width:768px){navbar-nav>li .noborder{      /* Before change */
@media (min-width:768px){navbar-nav>li.noborder{       /* After change  */
```

Your initial code targets a `.noborder` child of `li`.

The change targets the `li` with the class of `noborder`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
.noborder img {border:none;}
```

And if that doesn't work, then

```
.noborder img {border:none!important}
```